# Open form F2 from form F1, then uninstall form F1

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I know this has been asked as a question multiple times, where form A starts another form B and then A needs to be closed, and B needs to continue running. But, the problem I have is A is not only closed but also deleted as an installer is included as well.

The process is:

An installer installs both A and B, A is the main form. When A is started it checks if there is a new version. If there is, A needs to start form B **separately**, so that B can call a .bat script that will uninstall A, and replace it from a server with the latest version. (B is a simple form with 1 label - Updating, please wait). The problem is when B is called, it calls the .bat file which proceeds to uninstall A meaning it also kills A, and A also kills B. So when the uninstall happens, the please wait form is gone and the process stops.

What i've tried so far is trying to start B in A's Program.cs in a new thread so that it will be "independent" from A, but with no success

```
var t = new System.Threading.Thread(ThreadProc);
t.Start();
Close();

public static void ThreadProc()
{
    Application.Run(new B());
}
```

I also tried calling B without a thread, but as soon as A is uninstalled, B dies too.

```
Application.Run(new B());
or
var b = new B();
```

If i manually run the B (update) form from a folder, it uninstalls A, and installs the latest one. Is there a way to achieve this from inside the A form, so that it calls B independently which can then finish the process?

Comment: What do you mean by "installing"? A form can't be installed alone. Talk about an executable or a DLL.

Comment: You need to use instance(s) of the form.  See my two form project : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net

Comment: It's an executable. When talking about running/installing/uninstalling forms those are executables, sorry.

Comment: You can use the `show()` and `hide` of instance form.

Comment: If both forms are part of the same executable, as they appear to be, you can't unload and "uninstall" one but not the other.

Comment: @jdweng I'm not sure i can use your project, as my 2 forms are in 2 different projects

Comment: It doesn't matter that they are in different project.  The form is still a class that you need to reference by an instance even though they may be in different libraries (namespaces).

Comment: @Amy they are not, separate projects and separate executables. A has a reference to B

Comment: If A has a reference to B, they aren't separate executables.

Answer (score 1):

If by forms you mean executables...then you just need to Kill the process.

```
using System.Diagnostics;

Process bProcesss = Process.Start("C:\B.exe");
// do something
bProcess.Kill();
```

In your case you might need something like this to call from B.exe

```
Static void Main()
{
    KillProcess("A_Program");
}
private static void KillProcess(string processName)
{
    Process[] runningProcesses = Process.GetProcesses();
    foreach (Process process in runningProcesses)
    {
        if (process.ProcessName == processName)
        {
            process.Kill();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, this works perfectly fine - if i just run the executable as a process. What i got stuck with is trying to call the B form from inside A, and not it's executable if that makes any sense

Comment: @Filip5991 You run a bat file like this System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("c:\\batchfilename.bat");